# Loop using a template variable not working?

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-errors

Here is my situation:

I made a function called `MyFunction` 
 `MyFunction` accepts two arrays using parameter definitions `template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t M1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t M2>`. 
Then I made `MyFunction` as follows:

```
void MyFunction(double (&W)[N1][M1],double (&TD)[N2][M2]){
```

And in `MyFunction` I have a `for` loop like this `for(int i; i<N1; i++){...}`.

It won't compile and there is also has a warning saying:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions.

I don't know what this warning means. If anybody knows why this is happening please help. :)

Comment: To cast the warning away change your for loop to `for(std::size_t i; i<N1; i++){...}`. For the error you'll have to post code.

Comment: You'll also want to initialize `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::size_t` is an unsigned type and `int` is a signed type. The warning is very clear: you are trying to compare `i`, which is of a signed type, with `N1`, which is of an unsigned type. And you presumably have `-Werror` turned on or something like that.

The reason why this warning exists is that you can get counterintuitive results. For example, `-1 < (std::size_t)(0)` is most likely *false*, since `-1` will most likely be converted to `std::size_t` and end up as a large positive value. (Technically, this happens because the relational operators perform the *usual arithmetic conversions,* which favour unsigned types over signed types of equal or lesser width.)

However, many people also disable this warning, because the use of an `int` loop control variable is extremely common and usually benign. Just make sure you can't get any negative numbers.